# Move to next input after maxlength react functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am Using react-Hook-form, I have a scenario for a phone number that has three Input Field XXX-XXX-XXXX. I want to shift focus from the first input to the next after it reaches maxlength===3.please suggest a solution to auto Focus on the next phone input after reaches max length. working on react functional component.

Here is the code,

````
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export function PhoneInput(props) {
 const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    clearErrors,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();

return (

 <form className="review-your-info-form" id="purchase-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
<div className="field">
                    { (errors.phone1 || errors.phone2 || errors.phone3)  && <div className="error-msg"><span className="required">{errors.phone1?.message || errors.phone2?.message || errors.phone3?.message}</span></div>}
                    <label htmlFor="phone1">Phone *</label>
                    <div className="phone-group flex">
                      <input
                        id="phone1"
                        type="tel"
                        className="phone1"
                        maxLength="3"
                        onClick={() => clearErrors("phone1")}
                        {...register("phone1",{
                          required: 'phone-error',
                          minLength: {
                            value: 3,
                            message: 'phone-error'
                          },
                          pattern: {
                            value: /[2-9][0-9]{2}$/,
                            message: 'phone-error'
                          },
                        })}
                      />
                      <input
                        type="tel"
                        className="phone2"
                        maxLength="3"
                        onClick={() => clearErrors("phone2")} 
                        {...register("phone2",{
                          required: 'phone-error',
                          minLength: {
                            value: 3,
                            message: 'phone-error'
                          },
                          pattern: {
                            value: /[2-9][0-9]{2}$/,
                            message: 'phone-error'
                          },
                        })}
                      />
                      <input
                        type="tel"
                        className="phone3"
                        maxLength="4"
                        onClick={() => clearErrors("phone3")} 
                        {...register("phone3",{
                          required: 'phone-error',
                          minLength: {
                            value: 4,
                            message: 'phone-error'
                          },
                          pattern: {
                            value: /^[0-9]*$/i,
                            message: 'phone-error'
                          },
                        })}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
 </form>
)}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move focus in React you could use `useRef` hook:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export function PhoneInput(props) {
 const [input, setInput] = useState();
 const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    clearErrors,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();

const inputToFocus = useRef(); //<-- create ref

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
    if (e.target.value.length >= 3) inputToFocus.current.focus(); //<--- focus second input
}

return (

 <form className="review-your-info-form" id="purchase-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
<div className="field">
                    { (errors.phone1 || errors.phone2 || errors.phone3)  && <div className="error-msg"><span className="required">{errors.phone1?.message || errors.phone2?.message || errors.phone3?.message}</span></div>}
                    <label htmlFor="phone1">Phone *</label>
                    <div className="phone-group flex">
                      <input
                        value={input}
                        onChange={handleChange} //<-- edit input
                        id="phone1"
                        type="tel"
                        className="phone1"
                        maxLength="3"
                        onClick={() => clearErrors("phone1")}
                        {...register("phone1",{
                          required: 'phone-error',
                          minLength: {
                            value: 3,
                            message: 'phone-error'
                          },
                          pattern: {
                            value: /[2-9][0-9]{2}$/,
                            message: 'phone-error'
                          },
                        })}
                      />
                      <input
                        ref={inputToFocus}  //<-- assing ref
                        type="tel"
                        className="phone2"
                        maxLength="3"
                        onClick={() => clearErrors("phone2")} 
                        {...register("phone2",{
                          required: 'phone-error',
                          minLength: {
                            value: 3,
                            message: 'phone-error'
                          },
                          pattern: {
                            value: /[2-9][0-9]{2}$/,
                            message: 'phone-error'
                          },
                        })}
                      />
                      <input
                        type="tel"
                        className="phone3"
                        maxLength="4"
                        onClick={() => clearErrors("phone3")} 
                        {...register("phone3",{
                          required: 'phone-error',
                          minLength: {
                            value: 4,
                            message: 'phone-error'
                          },
                          pattern: {
                            value: /^[0-9]*$/i,
                            message: 'phone-error'
                          },
                        })}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
 </form>
)}
```

Explanation: the first input has to pass the focus to the second input when value reach length of 3 so:

1. I create a `inputToFocus` ref and assign to the second input;
2. then I create `handleChange` function to: set the first input value and, in case of value length >= 3, move the focus to second input using ref previously created.

Comment: Hi, I tried the above solution but it seems not to work for me. :(

Comment: @rajathhs provide me more details os we can debug together your problem =)

Comment: I have tried your above code in code editor https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-breeze-ur1k1?file=/src/App.js.  looks like after max-length focus needs to move to the next field. but it is not happening here. please let me know if I have missed anything?

Comment: @rajathhs your problem is on `...register("phone1"`  object. I don't know why but if you remove it in all input my solution it works. I removed also `onClick`. I modified your codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-platform-hv855?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Hi, @Giovanni Esposito yes you were right due to the react-hook-form register It was not working. I fixed by calling onChange and ref={inputToFocus} after register. :) it works fine now. Thanks for the help

Comment: @rajathhs happy to help you. Have a nice coding =)

Answer (score 0):

For an updated answer: I had the same Issue and I fixed it with React Hook Form API using Watch and setFocus, so you watch all inputs and if they change, then you "jump" to the next input with setFocus. This way you don't need to rely on useRef:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export function PhoneInput(props) {
 const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    setFocus,
    clearErrors,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();

   const watchAllInputs = watch() // With this you watch all inputs when change
   
  
   useEffect(() => watchAllInputs.hasOwnProperty("phone1") && (watchAllInputs.phone1.length > 3 && setFocus("phone2")), [watchAllInputs]  )


return (

 <form className="review-your-info-form" id="purchase-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
<div className="field">
                    { (errors.phone1 || errors.phone2 || errors.phone3)  && <div className="error-msg"><span className="required">{errors.phone1?.message || errors.phone2?.message || errors.phone3?.message}</span></div>}
                    <label htmlFor="phone1">Phone *</label>
                    <div className="phone-group flex">
                      <input
                        id="phone1"
                        type="tel"
                        className="phone1"
                        maxLength="3"
                        onClick={() => clearErrors("phone1")}
                        {...register("phone1",{
                          required: 'phone-error',
                          minLength: {
                            value: 3,
                            message: 'phone-error'
                          },
                          pattern: {
                            value: /[2-9][0-9]{2}$/,
                            message: 'phone-error'
                          },
                        })}
                      />
                      <input
                        type="tel"
                        className="phone2"
                        maxLength="3"
                        onClick={() => clearErrors("phone2")} 
                        {...register("phone2",{
                          required: 'phone-error',
                          minLength: {
                            value: 3,
                            message: 'phone-error'
                          },
                          pattern: {
                            value: /[2-9][0-9]{2}$/,
                            message: 'phone-error'
                          },
                        })}
                      />
                      <input
                        type="tel"
                        className="phone3"
                        maxLength="4"
                        onClick={() => clearErrors("phone3")} 
                        {...register("phone3",{
                          required: 'phone-error',
                          minLength: {
                            value: 4,
                            message: 'phone-error'
                          },
                          pattern: {
                            value: /^[0-9]*$/i,
                            message: 'phone-error'
                          },
                        })}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
 </form>
)}
```